# Customer attribute with Image upload throwing error

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I've created one customer attribute with input type, Check below code for reference.

```
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $setup->startSetup();
    $attributesInfo = [
        'upload_documents' => [
            'label' => 'Upload Document',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'image',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            "source" => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'position' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]
    ];
    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }
    $magentoUsernameAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'upload_documents');
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'],
    ]);
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
```

This is working fine, I can upload image from registration form. Its working with all image type but when I upload PDF it also working it display's PDF at backend.

Issue happens when I try to save customer which has PDF document its shows me error.

**"Upload Document" is not a valid image format**

Also after I can't upload PDF files from backend too.

Does anyone has what is I'm missing here ?? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default magento does not allow PDF format on upload to make this an option you will need to create a basic extension and include

app/code/CustomVendor/CustomModule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="resizeParameters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="height" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                <item name="width" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
                <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
                <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="dirs" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="exclude" xsi:type="string"/>
                <item name="include" xsi:type="string"/>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but its for WYSIWYG editor, I need it for for customer attribute.

Comment: Yeah the Wysiwygs use the same functionality and the same paramerters for uploads so if you put this in place it should work i have tested this on a number of methods